# How to make a block with positioned elements responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position

There is a block with elements and I need to make it adaptive. The problem is with the front block (gray square). What are the options for creating responsiveness?

[image]

HTML code for a block with a lot of elements:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="best">
    <div class="best__item">
      <div class="best__container">
      <img class="best__photo" src="css/img/best_03.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="best__back">
          <div class="best__back-subtitle">Daily</div>
          <div class="best__back-title">Inspiration</div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="best__number">01</div>
    </div>
    <div class="best__item">
      <div class="best__subtitle">Events <span>02 Jan</span></div>
      <div class="best__title">Lorem ipsum welcomes new fashion brand</div>
      <div class="best__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit nullam congue libero erat, eget aliquam dolor fermentum at.</div>
      <a href="#" class="work__btn">CHECK MORE</a>
      <div class="best__sub">
        <div class="best__title-sub">Best outfit</div>
        <div class="best__text-sub">from our stuff</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code for a block with a lot of elements:

```
.best {
    display: flex;
    padding: 80px 0 19.2% 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.best:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background: #E8E8E8;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.best__item {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.best__item:first-child:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 174%;

    background: #fff;

    position: absolute;
    top: -80px;
    right: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.best__item:last-child {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 179px 0 50px;
}

.best__photo {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.best__back {
    width: 700px;
    height: 530px;
    background: #E8E8E8;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -44%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.best__container {
    padding: 50% 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.best__back-subtitle {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 1.24;
    color: #b2b2b2;
}

.best__back-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    color: #000;
}

.best__number {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;

    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 240px;
    line-height: 1.6;

    background: linear-gradient(to top, 
    #E8E8E8 46%, #fff 20%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

    position: absolute;
    top: 58%;
    right: 5%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.best__subtitle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 25px;

    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #5d257c;
}

.best__subtitle span {
    color: #b2b2b2;
}

.best__title {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1.33;
    color: #000;
}

.best__title:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 30px 0;

    background-color: #000;
}

.best__text {
    margin-bottom: 40px;

    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 2.25;
    color: #b2b2b2;
}

.best__sub {
    text-align: center;

    position: absolute;
    top: 150%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.best__title-sub {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    color: #000;
}

.best__text-sub {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 1.24;
    color: #b2b2b2;
}
```

I have reproduced the elements of the layout using borders:
[image]

Comment: Absolute positioning can be a bag of worms. I'd refactor to use transforms (translation) or other more manageable techniques.

Comment: The main thing is that this block looks good on devices of different sizes (you can change the positions of the elements, but on a large screen the block should look like in the image) and all the elements must be present

Comment: Please revise your question. That information doesn't belong down here where others have to scour for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of absolute position, you can use a grid layout and share a few cells with different containers:

Possible example:

```css
html {
  background: #eee
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;  /* could be any other container , header, section ... */
  grid-template-columns: 1.45fr 1.85fr 1.7fr 1.5fr 1.5fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 40px 120px 120px 140px auto;
}

body:after {
  content: '';
  background: gray;
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 1 / span 5;
}

section {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 1 / span 5;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

div {
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 2 /span 2;
  grid-column: 2 /span 2;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/227/400/300) 0 0 / cover;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2 /span 2;
  grid-column: 4 /span 2;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background: lightgray;
  align-items: center;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
  grid-column: 3 /span 2;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #777a;
  padding: 0px 0px 20px 30px;
}

div:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 4 / span 2;
  grid-column: 3 /span 3;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

a {
  appearance: button;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div>
  <h2> lorem Ipsum</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  <a href="">Link</a>

</div>
<div>Inspiration</div>
<div>01</div>
<div>Bust parboulum</div>
<section>whatever comes next...</section>
```

Useful resources about grid:

- https://gridbyexample.com/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

From there, [`minmax()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) and/or media queries can help rearrange the layout.

Comment: I haven't used grid much (mostly flexbox), and I hadn't realized that you could "share" grid cells across multiple layers. What a great strategy!